# Cache-Control warning getting logged when add ResponseCache attribute

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I have ASP.NET Core 2.2 application. I have set `no-store=true` on all controllers for the cases when the user clicks the browser's back button

```
[ResponseCache(NoStore = true)]
public class MyController:Controller
{
}
```

and in startup.cs i am adding AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
            {   
                options.Filters.Add(new AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());                

            })
```

however for every request i see a warning getting logged

> The 'Cache-Control' and 'Pragma' headers have been overridden and set
>   to 'no-cache, no-store' and 'no-cache' respectively to prevent caching
>   of this response. Any response that uses antiforgery should not be
>   cached.

I understand that Any response that uses antiforgery should not be cached and i do have `NoStore=true` set. So why there is warning.

If i remove `[ResponseCache(NoStore = true)]` then warning is gone. However i need to that attribute in cases where user click back button

Answer (score 12):

`NoStore` ist not enough. The warning is a result of the default antiforgery logic checking both the 'cache-control' and 'pragma' header values for 'no-cache'. If the 'cache-control' header does not contain 'no-cache' or the 'pragma' header is anything else but either 'no-cache' or empty, that warning is created.

You always have to include the location in your cache settings:

```
[ResponseCache(Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
```

This will set the 'cache-control' header to 'no-store,no-cache' as well as the 'pragma' header to 'no-cache' and the warning will not be created.